# How to rescale a continuously rotating element to fit exactly in its (fixed size) container?

Tags: css, rotation, css-animations, scale

I let a (rectangular) image rotate infinitely. While rotating, I would like to adjust its size (so that the image doesn't get cut off).
*In other words:* I try to display the whole image always as large as possible.

[image: Current result, which gets cut off.]

The "0 deg" example is therefore correct, but the "80 deg" one would rather look like:

[image: The desired result.]

As you might have noticed, this is executed as a StreamElements-widget. That's propably the reason why `overflow:visible` doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <img src="some_url">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    
    overflow:visible;
    
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    
    object-fit: contain;
    
    animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

I thought that `transform: ... scale(x)`may work, but I wasn't able to do it without using fixed keyframe values (which seems like a unreliable solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't get your way through this without Javascript and also transform the element in Javascript instead of CSS.
Here is how I would do it, I didn't reproduce your exact example, I used 2 simple divs : one container and another one inside the first one (instead of the image) ;

```js
const cont= document.querySelector('.main-container');
const rot= document.querySelector('.rotater');
const H= rot.offsetHeight, h= cont.offsetHeight;
const W= rot.offsetWidth;

var t=0;

var anim= setInterval(rotate, 20);
function rotate(){
    rot.style.transform= "rotate(-" + t + "deg)";
    update(t);
    t++;
}

function update(T){
    let alpha= Math.atan(H/W);
    let diagLength= Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(H, 2) + Math.pow(W, 2));
    let theta= degToRad(T);
    theta= radTrunc(theta);
    theta= (theta> Math.PI/2 && theta< Math.PI) || (theta> 3*Math.PI/2 && theta< 2*Math.PI) ? Math.PI - theta : theta;
    let beta= (Math.PI/2) - (alpha + theta);
    let nonScaledHeight= Math.cos(beta) * diagLength;
    let ratio= Math.abs(h/nonScaledHeight);
    ratio= ratio> 1 ? 1 : ratio;
    rot.style.transform += " scale(" + ratio + ")";
}

function degToRad(angle){
 return angle * Math.PI / 180;
}

function radTrunc(angle){
    while(angle> (Math.PI * 2)){
        angle -= Math.PI*2;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

```css
    .main-container{
        width: 600px;
        height: 200px;
        background: blue;
    }
    .rotater{
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        background: green;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="rotater"></div>
</div>
```

All the computing you see in the function `update` is basic trigonometry, we compute the height that the inner div would take when rotated : `nonScaledHeight` and the ratio of that value with the height of the outer div would be the scaling ratio of the inner div.
`degToRad`converts the angle `t`from degrees to radians and `radTrunc` makes sure that the angle stays in the range `[0, 2*PI[`.

Comment: Oh, and `setInterval(rotate, 20)` will give your inner div a rotation of `t` degrees every 20milliseconds wich is 50° per second so if you want you picture to perform a complete 360° rotation in 5s, you should use `rot.style.transform= "rotate(-" + t * 20*360/5000 +"deg)"`.